Is there any reason to keep coax cables running to various parts of the house?
The previous owners of my place liked their TV and had coax cable running to the living room and all three bedrooms, through the unfinished basement.  I’m  pretty much ready to rip it all out and replace it with CAT6, but first, is there any reason why I might want to keep it?  Some kind of cool project I could do with it?

cables are forever, keep it

You use coax to carry Ethernet.  Look for Ethernet to coax converters, or MoCA converters.

@SteveSh You can do the whole converter thing. But personally, I highly recommend proper 4-pair twisted pair  cables, except when there is no practical option. "through the unfinished basement" means this won't be that hard a job. Different sometimes when all walls finished or buried cable to an outbuilding, etc.

Sure, if you're talking about pulling new media (cable, fiber, etc).  I was just suggesting an option to make use of existing coax that in some places is probably behind finished walls.

the best use for them is to use them to pull new CAT6 w/o fish tape or frustration. You can also make a simple  whole-house music/intercom or analog video network using CH3/4 RF switches or VCRs or HDTV adapters; a sorta-neat project.

This is pretty close to an opinion type of question and at risk to be closed, but I'll toss mine in anyway.
Cables in the wall can serve, if not stapled or otherwise secured, as pull strings for future purposes. If you're considering to rip it out and put in CAT6, using the coax as pull lines shows you how well that would work, but also consider to use an additional pull cord attached along with the CAT6, giving you the future option.
I installed PVC for CAT5 video camera purposes throughout the house, but added one more line. Adding a PowerWall later meant that the pull string was useful for the comm line and I also asked the tech to pull a new line alongside.
Even if you don't use it ever, future owners may be happy to see the extra line as an option, or you will when you have to replace it with fiber optics.
